# How to write sql that retrieves last changes

Tags: sql, oracle10g, max

```
43  RÜQİİ, Siyəzən QİS   960037  9900001621  5  2455239  25022  
44  RÜQİİ, Sumqayıt QİS  960077  9900001621  6  2455092  43395  
45  RÜQİİ, Sumqayıt QİS  960077  9900001621  5  2455092  47185  
46  RÜQİİ, Tovuz QİS     960060  9900001621  5  2455240  39237  
47  RÜQİİ, Tərtər QİS    960059  9900001621  5  2455240  39244
```

Hi guys. When I select from database it returns me result like this. the 7th column is "STATECHANGETIME" And I want to write sql that returns just the last change(the max value of 7th column)

And my sql is:

```
SELECT ORG.DESCRIPTION, ORG.EXTERNALKEY, P.VALUE AS VOEN, AGR.STATECODE, AGR.STATECHANGEDATE, AGR.STATECHANGETIME
FROM organization org, AGREEMENT AGR, PROPERTY P, PMTSVCAGREEMENT PSA
WHERE     AGR.RECEIVERID = ORG.ID AND P.ID = ORG.ID AND PSA.ID=AGR.ID
    AND P.IDX = 4 AND (org.ownerid = (SELECT id 
                                      FROM organization
                                      WHERE externalkey = '960000') 
    OR ORG.EXTERNALKEY = '960000')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN ORG.EXTERNALKEY = '960000' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ORG.DESCRIPTION;
```

How to write it.
Thank u

I want this result to retrieve:

```
43  RÜQİİ, Siyəzən QİS   960037  9900001621  5  2455239  25022    
44  RÜQİİ, Sumqayıt QİS  960077  9900001621  5  2455092  47185  
45  RÜQİİ, Tovuz QİS     960060  9900001621  5  2455240  39237  
46  RÜQİİ, Tərtər QİS    960059  9900001621  5  2455240  39244
```

Comment: Instead of an image can you post text with the correct data to test?

Comment: Edit your question to add the data, inserting on the comment is not usefull, it looses all the formatting

Comment: there are 7 columns on the result but the select has only 6, or the first numbers are just row numbers?

Comment: the first row is just row numbers. it doesnt matter

Comment: There are more tables involved on the query: `AGREEMENT, PROPERTY, PMTSVCAGREEMENT`

Answer (score 0):

Without more information I guess [this code](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9ca95/13) could help you. It gets the set ordered by `STATECHANGEDATE, STATECHANGETIME` on descending order and then gets the first returned set of values by using the

```
WHERE ROWNUM <= 1
```

Hope it helps.